# Suppose $a_n\rightarrow2$. Give an $\varepsilon-N$ proof that ${a_n}^2\rightarrow4$.

Tags: real-analysis

and show that ${a_n}^2\rightarrow L\implies |a_n|\rightarrow L $

To go about proving it in the $\implies$ direction:

[image]

Now, obviously, on the last line, I want to get that $4+4\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2 <4+\varepsilon$.

Could someone (at least hint to) fill in the gap?
And conversely, how would I go about structuring it?
Thanks

Comment: You are using the triangle inequality incorrectly, $|a_n-2|\le |a_n|-|2|$ is typically false. We have $|a_n-2|\le |a_n|+2$, which is not particularly useful here, and also $|a_n|\le|a_n-2|+2$.

Comment: As for a converse, not only does $a_n^2 \to 4$ not imply that $a_n \to 2$, it doesn't even imply that $a_n$ converge to anything—for example, if $a_n := (-1)^n 2$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ doesn't exist, but $a_n^2 = 4$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $a_n^2-4=(a_n-2)(a_n+2)$

Comment: Sub-hint: $|a_n-2|\leqslant1\implies|a_n+2|\leqslant5$.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: If $(a_n) \to a$ and $(b_n)\to b$ then $(a_n \cdot b_n)\to a\cdot b$

Proof: Given $\varepsilon>0$. Let $N$ sufficient large such that $|a_n-a|<\min\bigg(1, \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1+|b|)} \bigg)$ and $|b_n-b|< \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1+|a|)} $ ocurrs simultaneously.  Since $|a_n-a|<1$ it follows that $|a_n|<1+|a|$. Thus for all $n> N$ we have:

\begin{align}|a_nb_n-ab|=|a_nb_n-ab+a_nb-a_nb|<|a_n||b_n-b|+|b||a_n-a|\\
<(1+|a|) |b_n-b|+|b||a_n-a|\\
<\varepsilon \end{align}

Since $a_n^2= a_n \cdot a_n$ and $(a_n) \to 2$ then by the above lemma it follows that $a_n^2 \to 4$

Comment: That's all well and good, but the point is that we are not allowed to use the Algebra of Limits (which you've derived). I have to do an $\varepsilon-N$ proof for this particular case. But I don't see how the above hints are helpful.

Comment: Try to do exactly the same that I did but for this particular case.